# Resetting bibliography numbering using multibib and moderncv

Tags: bibtex, numbering, moderncv, multibib

I have two files, `art1.bib`:

```
@article{article1,
  title={Journal Article},
  author={Man},
  year={2014},
  journal={Journal}
}
```

and `conf1.bib`:

```
@article{magazine1,
  title={Magazine Article},
  author={Woman},
  year={2014},
  journal={Magazine}
}
```

When I compile the file `mwe.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\firstname{Hi}
\familyname{There}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{art,conf}{{Articles},{Conferences}}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Publications}
\nociteart{*}
\bibliographystyleart{plain}
\bibliographyart{art1}
\nociteconf{*}
\bibliographystyleconf{plain}
\bibliographyconf{conf1}    
\end{document}
```

I get this:

[image]

How to reset the numbering so the second bibliography will start from 1 as well?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You simply have to load `multibib` with the option `resetlabels`:

```
\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\firstname{Hi}
\familyname{There}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}
\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
\newcites{art,conf}{{Articles},{Conferences}}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Publications}
\nociteart{*}
\bibliographystyleart{plain}
\bibliographyart{art1}
\nociteconf{*}
\bibliographystyleconf{plain}
\bibliographyconf{conf1}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]