# How to use multiple bibliographies, with later ones only showing new citations?

Tags: bibtex, citing

I wish to typeset a document in two parts, A and B.
Say I have 10 citations in part A. I want to include a bibliography listing those at the end of part A.

In part B, citations that are already covered in the bibliography in part A should simply reuse numbers 1-10. 
New citations should get numbers starting from 11. A bibliography at the end of part B should only display numbers from 11 and up.

How may I accomplish this? So far I've only been able to find solutions where the bibliography starts from scratch, i.e. starts enumerating from 1 and relists works previously cited.

EDIT: here's a simplified example of what I want:

```
Here's a reference[1]. Here's another[2].
Now I feel like making a list of references
Bibliography:
[1]: Article X
[2]: Article Y

Okay here's a reference that ways already included in the previous bibliograpy[1].
Here's a brand new one[3].
Now I feel like making a of all the references not included in the 
first bibliograpy:
Bibliography:
[3]: Article Z
```

Notice that 1) The citation number ([1]) for article X was 'reused' from the first bibliography and not listed again, 2) ONLY previously unseen citations where included in the second list, and 3) this is not tied to chapter/part/section numbers i.e. I'm not forced to create a new section/chapter/part for this to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Bibliographies one for each Chapter with Biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202281/multiple-bibliographies-one-for-each-chapter-with-biblatex)

Comment: Almost. However I don't want the numbering to be tied to chapter number (or section number of anything). Just the second bibliography to only show new entries.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. You can load `multibib` with the option `resetlabels` (i.e. `\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}`), see the `multibib` [manual p. 3](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/multibib/multibib.pdf), or [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215965/resetting-bibliography-numbering-using-multibib-and-moderncv).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why resetlabels should be used. That seems to reset the numbers to start from 1, whereas I want citations from the former part to reuse the numbers 1-10.
Loading without resetlabels sort of works but gives a lbel multiply defined warning every time I cite works from part A.

Comment: You mean e.g. "section [1] [2] section [11] [12] [13]"?

Comment: @ABlueChameleon did you remove a previous answer? I sat down to test it out and it seems to be gone.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I realized it didn't work as intended at all, and couldn't think of a way to fix the issue.